# Build Python with Mingw and gcc

Tags: python, gcc, mingw, mingw-w64

Is it possible to build Python interpreter from source with Mingw and gcc on Windows 7?
And I would like to biuld a 64bit version.

If a 64bit Python (gcc Mingw) version is available for download please let me know, I would use that also.
At the end I still would like to compile it with gcc and mingw.

Comment: Download the sources, read the docs, and run the compiler with appropriate flags. This doesn't apply only to MinGW :)

Comment: @StoryTeller your name is aptly chosen. Python does not build out of the box with MinGW, let alone for Win64.

Answer (score 8):

First off, you do not need to build Python with MinGW-w64 to link to it and embed a interpreter. Just extract the msi installer, and use the prebuilt DLL. Note you'll have to be careful not to mix msvcr[t|90].dll objects, but I've never seen that be a real issue personally.

MinGW-w64 gcc/ld should be able to link to DLL's directly, otherwise you'll have to use `gendef` [to create a .def file](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/gendef/) and `dlltool` [to create an import library](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Answer%20generation%20of%20DLL%20import%20library/).

Secondly, there's a [patchset to build Python with MinGW](http://bugs.python.org/issue3871), but I'm not sure about its 64-bit compatibility.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The reason for this, is I would like to compile Quantum-Gis for 64 bit with mingw and gcc. Quatum-Gis have capability for utilising plugins written in python or c++. For this I need Sip and PyQt4 in 64bit for Win7. I went through the gendef/nm process to create the libpython27.a file. I started to build Sip with Mingw and gcc and Python 2.7.3 all in 64bit, successfully, I also could test Sip in a python console. I successfully compiled PyQt4 and install it, but when testing it in a python console it just fails.

Comment: I don't know how to debug this failure?
Because of this failure I reasoned that maybe I need to compile Python 2.7.3 with mingw and gcc in 64bit. In your opinion, if I download pre-build 64 bit Sip and PyQt4 binaries that is build with MSVC, would I have problems later on with other python scripts/plugins written against these binaries?

Comment: @TheunsHeydenrych That I don't know. I would suggest asking the `mingw-w64-public@sourceforge.net` mailing list, where a couple of people use Python with MinGW-w64. All I do is link `gdb` to Python, which works as I described `;-)`.

Comment: Searching the tracker for 'mingw' returns about 50 open issues and 100 closed issues. Some of the recent open issues might be helpful.

Comment: Personally, I used a [mingw64 build](http://netcologne.dl.sourceforge.net/project/mingwbuilds/host-windows/releases/4.8.1/64-bit/threads-win32/seh/x64-4.8.1-release-win32-seh-rev5.7z) that already includes a version of python 2.7.

Answer (score 4):

You may try this repository:

hg clone https://bitbucket.org/puqing/python-mingw

It is a copy of the official repository but contains some modification to make it compile with mingw. Enter PC/MinGW directory:

cd PC/MinGW && make

Not sure if it compiles in win64, but with win32 and msys it should work.