# lldb on Windows, possible?

Tags: clang, llvm, lldb

I just build clang on Windows following [this](http://here-be-braces.com/blog/building-clang-natively-on-windows-mingw). To make it kind of complete it seems the compiler lldb should be made also.

How do I build lldb with mingw? Or it should be build with clang?

Answer (score 1):

The people who work on the Windows port of lldb use Visual Studio.  The instructions for building lldb on Windows are here:

http://lldb.llvm.org/build.html#BuildingLldbOnWindows

Comment: Link is broken, unfortunately.

Comment: FWIW: https://lldb.llvm.org/resources/build.html#id1

Answer (score 0):

Basically follow the build instructions for Linux:
http://lldb.llvm.org/build.html#BuildingLldbOnLinux

I recommend you to use ninja for windows instead of make (it's faster) but that's up to you.

Preferably use a mingw build of python. You find instructions on this here:
[Build Python with Mingw and gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365249/build-python-with-mingw-and-gcc)

Alternatively you can use cmake for python build:
https://github.com/python-cmake-buildsystem/python-cmake-buildsystem

In the chapter "Building LLDB" itself use the latest stable source from llvm, cland and lldb and rename the folder as shown in the directory hierarchy image.

If you want to try building llvm and clang with clang, try to put a build of clang + llvm in your path (and avoid VC + gcc). In this case you might need a clang-build of python too. I did not try this out.

If you get build errors try to use the headers from predef.sf.net.