# Linking Python within Mingw

Tags: python, windows, bash, gcc, mingw

I want to execute a software that was written for linux initially and uses python and c code . Therefore i installed MinGW including mysys.

Under Linux you start a run.sh script that starts the program:

```
#! /bin/bash
python some_script.py -i somefile.abc -q
```

however when i open the MinGw shell and execute the script i get the follwing promt:

```
$ Python
sh: Python: command not found
```

Python is installed under C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27  in windows 7.

Inside the "fstab" file under "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\etc" i added the following lines:

```
# Win32_Path                Mount_Point
#-------------------------------------  -----------
C:/MinGW                /mingw
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27         /python
```

MinGw and mysys are in windows path.

I found the following threads while searching but they do not seem related at all:
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731100/link-to-python-with-mingw)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365249/build-python-with-mingw-and-gcc)

Do i understand my problem correctly, that i have to tell MinGW where the windows python installation is located?

Comment: Has the C been compiled on Windows?  Is that what you are trying to do?  Is the C calling python or is python calling C?

Comment: python is calling C in the program i want to use. But even without this being the case MinGW should see my python installation shouldn't it? Even if i type `Python` directly to the shell it doesn´t find it..

Comment: Can it be realted to the fact, that the PATH  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27` contains spaces?

Comment: Did you use `Python` or `python`?  Does `python` work on `cmd.exe`?

Comment: python works in cmd .. it also works if i use `C:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Python27/python` in MinGW. Guess its smart to install stuff were the default installer tells you. Linux ports dont work good with spaces it seems. Unfotunately i reinstall is not an option at the moment....